# Volume between a sphere and cone in off-axis case

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

I was wondering if there is a way to solve for the overlapping volume between a cone and sphere where the cone's axis isn't necessarily aligned with the sphere's. Here's an image showing a possible case of [overlapping volumes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urlES.png) ([source](https://www.grad.hr/geomteh3d/prodori/prodor_sf_eng.html)). I know that the overlap becomes simpler in the case of an aligned axis (e.g. [Finding the volume between a cone and a sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067858/finding-the-volume-between-a-cone-and-a-sphere)) but I'm interested in the more general case.

Let the cone have an opening angle $\alpha$, height $h$, and the sphere's radius is $R$. I know we could work in spherical coordinates and try to integrate over the overlapping region between the two shapes to solve for the volume. But the [curve of intersection](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cone-SphereIntersection.html) is quite complicated so I'd expect that such an integral can only be solved numerically for fixed values of $\alpha$, $h$, and $R$. I was wondering if such an integral could be solved without resorting to numerics or if there is an alternative way to solve this problem?

Comment: Using spherical coordinate systems with origin in cone vertex can give something. $x=r \sin u \cos v$, $y=r\sin u \sin v$, $z=r \cos u$. Range of $r$ can be determined from $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2 \leq R^2$ which is quadratic inequality in respect to $r$. But I don't know if the resulting integral could be taken in closed-form.

Comment: The general intersecting volume is a rather messy sums of truncated cones, sphere caps and other volumes expressed by elliptic integrals. See https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.17227 .